# Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing Perhaps you forgot to surround the code with a step that provides this, such as: node

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, function-call

When i load another groovy file in Jenkinsfile it show me following error.

"Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing
Perhaps you forgot to surround the code with a step that provides this, such as: node"

I made a groovy file which contains a function and i want to call it in my Declarative Jenkinsfile. but it shows an error.

```
My Jenkinsfile--->

def myfun = load 'testfun.groovy'
pipeline{
    agent any
    environment{
        REPO_PATH='/home/manish/Desktop'
        APP_NAME='test'
    }
    stages{
        stage('calling function'){
            steps{
                script{
                    myfun('${REPO_PATH}','${APP_NAME}')
                }
             }
         }
     }
  }
```

Result--

org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.MissingContextVariableException: Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing
Perhaps you forgot to surround the code with a step that provides this, such as: node

Suggest me what is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

You either need to use a scripted pipeline and put "load" instruction inside the node section (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53950119/jenkins-pipeline-how-to-load-a-jenkinsfile-without-first-calling-node)) or if you are already using a declarative pipeline (which seems to be the case), you can include it in "environment" section:

```
environment {
    REPO_PATH='/home/manish/Desktop'
    APP_NAME='test'
    MY_FUN = load 'testfun.groovy'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is that due to earlier/underlying errors, the context has been removed for example by multiple executor machines. This happens if you are missing the node (e.g. script) -block, but especially at the post always -block. You can use the if -check also in other places. After this you get another error, that was causing this error message.

```
post {
  always {
    script {
       //skip the step if context is missing
       if (getContext(hudson.FilePath)) {
         echo "It works"
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

See https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci-kb/latest/troubleshooting-guides/how-to-troubleshoot-hudson-filepath-is-missing-in-pipeline-run

---

Answer (score 2):

We have to wrap with node {}, so that jenkins executors will execute on node, Incase if we would like to execute on any specific agent node, we can mention like node('agent name'){}

example here :

```
node {

def myfun = load 'testfun.groovy'
pipeline{
    agent any
    environment{
        REPO_PATH='/home/manish/Desktop'
        APP_NAME='test'
    }
    stages{
        stage('calling function'){
            steps{
                script{
                    myfun('${REPO_PATH}','${APP_NAME}')
                }
             }
         }
     }
  }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work, Jenkins complains about `pipeline` not being at the top level

Comment: move env declaration inside stage

Comment: same... `pipeline` should be at the top in a declarative syntax

Answer (score 2):

Loading the function in an initial script block inside the pipeline worked for me. Something like below:

```
def myfun

pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        REPO_PATH='/home/manish/Desktop'
        APP_NAME='test'
    }
    stages {
        stage('load function') {
            steps {
                script {
                    myfun = load 'testfun.groovy'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('calling function') {
            steps {
                script {
                    myfun("${REPO_PATH}","${APP_NAME}")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error message when I was calling a sh script that does not not exist in the repository / file system. Please look in the stack trace the following line:

```
at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:135)
```

The 135 marks the line in Jenkinsfile, on which the missing script or error is happening.